# Bootstrap 4 Column Ordering Conundrum

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I believe this was possible with Bootstrap 3, but am unsure as to how to implement the following with Bootstrap 4 (4.1).

I would like a column with C beneath A and another column with B, but on mobile, display ABC. See the example image below.

[image: Example]

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code in the question. As explained in the duplicate answer, you need to disable the flexbox responsively and float cols. https://www.codeply.com/go/RYDUXOFUgY

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the ability to insert 'B' between 'A' and 'C' when the screen size shrinks is supported by Bootstrap out-of-the-box.

However, it works nicely with a bit of custom CSS. This solution requires that the container (i.e. row) have a defined height.

```css
.pull-up {
  top: -50%;
}

.split-row-1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.split-row-2 {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row" style="height:50px;">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 split-row-2" style="background:red">A</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8 split-row-1" style="background:blue">B</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 split-row-2 pull-up" style="background:yellow">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That example collapses to the right layout, but on desktops, I want column C to be where column B is in your example. Can't figure out how to accomplish that. Appreciate the assist!

Comment: Oops, yeah you're right. Still working on it...

Comment: I updated my answer. Does that perform what you need?

Comment: Fantastic -- thank you very much!

Comment: In practice, setting the height in advance won't work too well for my use case, but it's a creative solution. Certainly deserving of an upvote IMO -- don't have the rep yet to do it, but will come back.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I'll let you know if I find an alternate solution.

Comment: @eclecticist There's no `col-xs` in Bootstrap 4. It's just `col`. Also you should only include one of the Bootstrap JS files. So either `bundle` or the normal one.

Comment: @Klooven Good tips! Thanks.